# How to use icon in Java applet?

Tags: java, image, applet, icons

[image]

I want to use my icon in a Java applet.  How can I do that?

Comment: These are OS specific look and feels, you may not have control over changing them ... Or is your question about getting that check from the Mac OS to work in your own program? Cause that's the same problem

Comment: Is the icon intended as an application resource?  E.G. is it an icon for a button or menu, or a background image?  Or alternately is it the 'media' displayed in (for example) an image slideshow?  Can you display an image in a frame?  Is the applet based on AWT or Swing?  Is it loading the image, or simply displaying it, that you are having trouble with?  To best help, I will need a clear answer for each question.  (My earlier answer has been deleted since it is entirely irrelevant to what you actually need.)

Comment: I just need to use my own icon on Java Applet run dialog.
http://i.imgur.com/b4iqo.jpg

Answer (score 2):

There are two different Platform Look and Feels there. But what I think you're getting at is that one is a signed application and one isn't.

There is a documented process you need to follow to sign your application so it doesn't have the warning icon and the unchecked box.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/index.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html

Comment: No.  The difference is in the way the code signing certificate was produced, and whether that certificate was issued by a CA.  See my answer.

Comment: Oops..  It turns out the question has nothing to do with trust dialogs!

Answer (score 2):

I am not pretty sure things you want to do with the restricted access dialog icon...

But, actually, the uploaded image you showed in your question it is NOT A PART OF "***your application***" but jre restricted access dialog.

[image]

It shows when you are trying to run a signed applet... It allows you :

- A) run your applet once with unrestricted access
- B) or place the applet cert to certs storage to make it trusted and run it with no
  security dialog later

It sounds strange but in other words your question is about "changing something on client machine JRE" :S So I guess it is a bad idea trying to change the jre "Warning-Security" dialog icon itself :S

---

Even if you starts a pretty correct signed applet once you still will have the restricted access dialog shown until you makes the cert trusted; So anyway the dialog will be shown even once for having cert trusted; It makes me think you anyhow cannot avoid having this dialog showing for your **signed** applet;

*Still you can make the restricted access dialog NEVER BEEN SHOWN; But the only way to do so is **keeping** your applet **in sandbox** frames using "unrestricted - the harmless" libraries in your applet project and your applet should be unsigned; For more detailed information what unsigned applet can do or what they're can't you can read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) tutorial;*

P.S.
In the case you meant something else in your question please do comment